# jQuery .show doesn't display the background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making the navigation bar for a website, and I want to add nice effects to it. Now there is a dropdown menu with submenu's, and I want those submenu's to slide in. But for some reason it doesn't show the background when animating, and the text goes on top of the border next to it. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/93pnvjy3/4/) is a link to what it looks like. There is something weird happening as well when hovering over multiple times.

```
for some reason I have to accompany links to jsfiddle.net with code, so here it is.
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems with it on Firefox.

Comment: ^ same, works in Chrome

Comment: You need to hover over `Vanilla > Creative` to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You missed setting the color for the the `#parnavdrop ul li`. 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93pnvjy3/5/)

```
#parnavdrop ul li {
  background-color: #41D4CF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is you have mentioned background-color to inherit.

```
.nav ul #navdrop #subnavdrop{
   background-color:inherit;
}
```

So it is inheriting background color from its parent which is causing the issue.

So the following code change can also resolve the issue.

```
.nav ul #navdrop #subnavdrop{
    background-color:#41D4CF;
}
```

Sometimes just because of these stop() functions JS functionality is not working properly

[image: error as seen on fiddle]